# Unfair die probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

**Hello, I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this one:**

An unfair die looks like an ordinary 4-sided die but the probability of a face landing on 2 is three times the probability of landing on 1. Similarly, the probability of landing on 3 is two times that of landing on 1 and the probability of landing on 4 is four times that of landing on 1. Let Y denote the number of dots on the "up" face.

- What is the probability distribution of Y?
- How could I determine the probability of it having, say, three dots?

Comment: Please check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add `[self-study]` tag accordingly.

Comment: I do not see this as a self-study question.

Answer (score 1):

It simply follows a [categorical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) (or [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) if you want to count the number of times it landed on each side, but that's not your question):

$$ \Pr(X = x) = \begin{cases}
\alpha   & \text{if }x=1, \\
3\alpha  & \text{if }x=2, \\
2\alpha  & \text{if }x=3, \\
4\alpha  & \text{if }x=4 
\end{cases} $$

such that $\alpha + 3\alpha + 2\alpha + 4\alpha = 1$ since probabilities need to sum up to unity. Solving it needs just a basic algebra.

Comment: I think a more interesting question is how do you physically shave the die to make this work.  Shaving a die makes the opposite sides have the same surface area.  The sides with the largest surface area have higher probability of occurrence.  On a standard die 3 is opposite to 4, 2 to 5 and 1 to 6.  If you ignore the effect of the number of dots on the face.  we need P(1)=P(6), P(2)=P(5) and P(3)=P(4) and                require P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4) + P(5) + P(6) =1.

Comment: The die is shaped this way in order to make it look similar to a cube.  I think it is important to note that a die has 6 sides! Tim has the concept right but the OP and Tim both fail to think about the physical shape of a cube.

Comment: @MichaelChernick there is a physical [four-side die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-sided_die). Moreover, this seems to be rather a basic probability/statistics homework question, then one asking about some real die and it's properties (interesting question for itself).

Comment: What does a three dimensional 4-sided die look like?  If it is a cube it has 6 sides.  I absolutely agree that assuming a 4-sided die exists you have given the right solution.  I actually gave you a plus for that.  Be aware that homework problems fall into the category of self-help whether the OP tags it that way or not.  So you are suppose to give hints rather than a complete answer.  With your reputation I would think you would know that.

Comment: @MichaelChernick it's a [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron)

Comment: @MichaelChernick There's several different designs for fair four-sided dice and several more that generate values between 1 and 4 but have more than four sides (e.g. 8-sided dice numbered 1-4 twice); I own several different kinds of four-sided dice.

Comment: I got my question answered @Glen_b.  I can imagine lots of 3 -D objects that can be called die and may physically exist.  Tim's example of a pyramid was satisfactory enough for me.  But we all know that the standard that gamblers use is the 6 sided cube.  There may be some intersting discussion on that with his new post.